# Finding index of a list containing an item, also in a list

Tags: python, list

Let's say my list is this:

```
Inventory = [["Item","Quantity"]["Credits","5000"]["Item 1", 2]["Item 3",1]]
```

I want to find the index in the primary list of the list that contains "Credits".

My current solution seems a little inelegant to me. In this code, I have a function that pulls the first item from each of the items in this list (It's useful in other situations, I can just bastardize it for this use). So it would give me ["Credits", "Item 1", "Item 2"]. I could use .index("Credits") on this and subtract 1 (Since the function ignores the first label item), but that feels like I'm jumping through a few unneeded hoops.

It *works*, yes. But I'm hoping there's something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` and list comprehension :

```
>>> Inventory = [["Item","Quantity"],["Credits","5000"],["Item 1", 2],["Item 3",1]]
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(Inventory) if j[0]=='Credits']
[1]
```

Comment: I knew there was something better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [["Item","Quantity"],["Credits","5000"],["Item 1", 2],["Item 3",1]]
>>> next( index for index,item in enumerate(l) if item[0] == "Credits")
1
```

Comment: A sentence or two to describe what you are providing goes a long way to make a quality Answer.